# Converting WITH statement from Postgres to mySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm working on porting a database system from PostgreSQL to mySQL but I can't get my head round this simply query?

The PostgreSQL query looks like the following:

```
query('WITH t as (UPDATE sessions SET expired = now() WHERE id = $1 AND ott = TRUE RETURNING *)' +
        'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT user_id FROM t)',
        [token], function(err, result) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            if (result.rows === 0) return callback('NOT_VALID_TOKEN');
            assert(result.rows.length === 1);
            callback(null, result.rows[0]);
        }
    );
```

However when trying to write this into mySQL as such:

```
WITH t as (UPDATE sessions SET expired = now() WHERE id = 1 AND ott = TRUE RETURNING *) SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT user_id FROM t)
```

It's throwing this:

```
1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While versions of MySQL before 8.0 do not support CTEs (`WITH` statements) it really doesn't matter since the big miss here is that MySQL doesn't support the `RETURNING` clause of the `UPDATE` statement like postgres does.

Instead you will need to execute two statements.

1. Update:

   ```
   UPDATE sessions SET expired = now() WHERE id = 1 AND ott = TRUE;
   ```
2. Select using the same predicates:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 AND ott = TRUE;
   ```

It's not as convenient as Postgres, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0 does support [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions): 
Earlier versions unfortunately do not.

You could try using [derived tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html) in the earlier versions.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) for more pointers.